# convert sorting algorithm to insertion sort

Tags: python, sorting, structure

The following code performs, what I believe is, a bubble sort.

```
def main():

  list=[5,3,1,6]
  print(list)
  for i in range((len(list))-1):#outer loop set to iterate for no of times:length of list -1 
    for i in range((len(list))-1):#loop to iterate through index elements and compare i+1 and i in the list
      if list[i+1]<list[i]:
        temp=list[i]
        list[i]=list[i+1]
        list[i+1]=temp
        print("Iteration:",i,"list:",list)
  print("Compared element 1 and 0:",list)

main()
```

Is there a quick way of converting this same style/method of implementing bubble sort into an insertion sort with minimal changes of code/variables?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but fun fact: you can swap variables in Python without a temporary variable. `list[i], list[i+1] = list[i+1], list[i]`

Comment: ^^ In fact, you can do it anywhere using XOR operator!

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1,(len(list))):#outer loop set to iterate for no of times:length of list -1 
    for j in range(i-1):#loop to iterate through o to i-1
      if list[i]<list[j]:
        list[i],list[j]=list[j],list[i]
```

Comment: I tried it like this, but doesn't seem to quite work: list=[5,4,3,2]
for i in range(1,(len(list))):#outer loop set to iterate for no of times:length of list -1 
    for j in range(i-1):#loop to iterate through o to i-1
      if list[i]<list[j]:
        list[i],list[j]=list[j],list[i]
        print(list)

Comment: Can you paste the entire code? I tried this, as mentioned above and doesn't quite work: https://trinket.io/python/13305cf4bc

Comment: This is basically the entire code, just have the list variable ready before you execute the loop structure. Here: https://ideone.com/LK8brr

Comment: That doesn't work at all. Try testing it with other value: e.g. https://repl.it/@teachyourselfpython/MagnificentPalegreenNematode

Comment: Thanks for trying though...I suspect it is very close. I also want the solution to be in a similar format to what my orginal bubble sort code is in!